# API Яндекс Карты. Показать и метку, и балун одновременно

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Здравствуйте.

Согласно дизайна нужно отображать одновременно и метку, и балун. 
Но по-умолчанию метка скрывается, если вызвать `balloon.open()`.
Как решить?

Благодарю.

Comment: `balloon.open('координаты', 'что выводить')` - без кода чем помочь?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нашел ответ в документации:

```
hideIconOnBalloonOpen: false
```